# How to remove Github workflow, Azure Webapp CD / CI with Github Repo

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

can someone help point a direction how to setup Azure Webapp with CD / CI please?
I have a github repo, which i want to connect to a url, when the master branch is updated.

I tried following tutorial, and try setup https://dev.azure.com/ account, to which I'm not sure how, but the url : http://bss-olr.azurewebsites.net/ seems to have been connected, although i cant see how to take down the github workflow. (ie: I want to take it down, and reuse the same URL again)

Can someone help point the right direction? Azure is quite confusing with many outdated documentations.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks all.. it turns out, i do still have the webapp running.. just that its not showing on the "recent resources" on landing dashboard page. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out this updated Azure tutorial: [Continuous deployment to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment?tabs=github). It shows you how to enable continuous deployment for your web app via the Azure portal.[image]

Comment: Thanks Grace.. any idea how to take down previously booked url? http://bss-olr.azurewebsites.net/ i dont have any webapp associated with that url anymore, bt somehow that url still linked to github workflow for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you could try to use the Azure CLI to remove the linked deployment resource.

For example:

```
az webapp deployment source delete --name MyWebApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

For more detailed steps , you could refer to this doc: [az webapp deployment source delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_deployment_source_delete)

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointer.. I tried this (although not directly source delete) the result i have was 1 liner..

'None' app doesn't exist

Thing is, the webapp for the github workflow is already deleted.. but the url https://bss-olr.azurewebsites.net/ still remains..